# webos / enyo: setting button size explicitly for both landscape and portrait. howto?

Tags: user-interface, webos, enyo

in webos / enyo, you can set the style field of buttons like so:

```
var style_DONE = "color: #fff; background-color: #2A4754; width: 92px"
```

here, i only set the width, and the height is taken care of by VFlexBox, and changes depending on the orientation(landscape/portrait) of the device.

How do i manually specify different sizes based on orientation?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different ways you might do this.  If you put all your style code in the .css file(s) you can add a class name to the  tag of your app (like **portrait** or **landscape**) on orientation change and then you would basically have two entries in the .css for a particular class like:

```
.portrait .myButton {/* styles */}
.landscape .myButton {/* styles */}
```

Then you would set **className: myButton** for each one, and so on.

You could also use media queries to determine device-height/device-width.

You could just set **max-height** or **min-height** maybe...the world is your oyster!

Comment: I'd suggest the media queries method - adjust size based on the width of the display rather than purely landscape or portrait, even if you just use the 1024/768 values of the current TouchPad.  This allows you to better deal with a variety of screen sizes.